# Pairwise calculations between raster layers from two different raster stacks

Tags: r, raster, pairwise

I have 2 raster stacks.  I want to do some math between pairs of raster layers from each of the stacks, producing a 3rd raster stack of the same number of layers, ie;

```
r1<- raster stack 1 # 10 raster layers
r2<- raster stack 2 # 10 raster layers

r3<- sqrt(r1^2 + r2^2) # 10 raster layers
```

Is this the equivalent of the loop form (for illustrative purposes);

```
for (i in 1:10) {
r <- sqrt(r1[[i]]^2 + r2[[i]]^2)
r3 <-stack(r3,r)
}
```

Or is there a more efficient *function* or *apply* solution? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `r3 <- sqrt((r1 ** 2) + (r2 ** 2))`?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I was asking.  So this is the same as the loop I showed taking each pair of raster layers?  I wondered if if had to unstack the raster stacks first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

You can indeed do

```
x <- sqrt(s^2 + s^2)
```

An alternative approach would be

```
y <- overlay(s, s, fun=function(x, y) { sqrt(x^2 + y^2) } )
```

The result is the same:

```
all(values(x-y) == 0)
#[1] TRUE
```

A difference is that if you use `overlay` you can provide a filename to write the result to disk